# Catching Ctrl+c on cygwin

Tags: go, cygwin, signals, ctrl

The following golang code catches <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> when run from a DOS prompt, but when I run it from Cygwin it doesn't catch anything when <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is pressed.

What does Cygwin do when <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is pressed?  My OS is Win7 64 bit running 32 bit Cygwin.

```
    func main() {
        c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
        signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt)
        go func(){
        for sig := range c {
            fmt.Println(sig.String())
        }
        }()

        time.Sleep(5000 * time.Millisecond) 
        fmt.Println("Done")
    }
```

Comment: In msys whether or not I get output on programs that catch interrupts depend on whether I use `go run` or `go build` followed by `whatever.exe`. Not sure if Cygwin has the same weirdness.

Comment: After typing `ctrl c terminal cygwin` into Google I'll guess your cygwin is < 1.7.18.

Comment: @Volker I Googled as well, that seems to be "ctrl+c doesn't work **at all**". There's a glut of completely separate questions about having trouble capturing signal interrupts from Windows programs run under Cygwin, which I haven't found a satisfactory response to yet (something about pseudoterminals or somesuch). What I'm getting is that it's possible that Cygwin sends a literal Unix SIGINT rather than whatever interrupt code Windows uses, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Volker - I have 1.7.24

Comment: @Jsor - My code doesn't catch signals from Cygwin in either case.  When I do `go run ...` Ctrl+c kills the `go run` process but the go program runs to completion.  When I do `./signal.catcher.exe` the Ctrl+c kills the program (doesn't run to completion).  The signals are not caught in either case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer I got on the cygwin mail list is that in order for signaling to work the program has to be compiled and linked with a Cygwin compiler and linker.  Cygwin is not a supported platform for golang, so I'm not going to be able to catch <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in a golang program launched from Cygwin.